# how to create a comment system using drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

halo  i'm working on a project that requires user to give a feedback whenever possible using django rest_framework
but im getting an some difficulties doing that
below is my code snippet & err msg

##mode file

```
class Review(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='review')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    reviewer_email = models.EmailField()
    rating = models.CharField(
        max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    review = models.TextField()
```

##serializer file

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('name',  'review', 'id', 'reviewer_email', 'rating')
 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        id = self.request
        print(self.request.user.profile)
        serializer.save(school=self.request.user.profile.school_id)
```

##apiView

```
class ReviewAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    permissions = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset = Review.objects.all()
```

err msg

```
    File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/files/project/django/schMrk/sch-market/schoolDetail/apiviews.py", line 213, in perform_create
    print(self.request.user.profile)
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'profile'
[04/Aug/2021 16:00:59] "POST /school-detail/add-review HTTP/1.1" 500 105554
```

can anyone help pls

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share the request body.
My guess(from the error) is that you didn't specify the id of the school object it should be related to

Answer (score 0):

You should limit access for non-authorized users. Otherwise, `self.request.user` could be an AnonymousUser object, which has no a profile relation.

```py
permissions = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```